# SQL Stored Porcedure returns 10mb XML file and adapter.Fill fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, xml

I have an issue where there is a stored procedure returning dynamically generated XML in a certain case the XML gets extremely large, if I were save it in a file it is 10mb.

I would like to to know if a `DataSet` or `DataTable` has a certain size limit, and if the size limit can be increased. This is on a ASP.NET site.

The stored procedure returns a `DataSet` with 3 `DataTables`, after waiting for about 2 minutes when trying to retrieve the XML the dataset is returned without throwing any exceptions, and 2 of the 3 data tables have data in them however the one containing the XML is empty.

Any suggestions or ideas as why this could be happening will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to to know if a DataSet or DataTable has a certain size limit, and if the size 
>   limit can be increased.

No size limit.

> This is on a ASP.NET site.

IIS can have a size limit for the website in memory. But that would trigger a restart of the website. Would look different.

> The stored procedure returns a dataset with 3 DataTables

Definitely NOT. Stored procedures can not return data tables, they return data in table form. Your code is transforming that into a data table. Stored prcedures do not care whether you use proper objects or something like a data table.

I Would suggest removing the data tables for the moment and anlysing the raw output with the proper low level interfaces- see what you get, how much you get, then moving that step by step into a data table.

Also, 10mb is not exactly a lot - proper debugging should give you an idea what goes wrong.